# Silverstripe 3 doPublish in Controller

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

in an old silverstripe installation (2.4) i had a little counter function that looks basically like this:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
  public function countUp(){ 
    $this->Counter = $this->Counter+1;
    $this->writeToStage('Stage');
    $this->publish("Stage", "Live");
  }
}
```

I want to move that over to SS 3.
Somehow it does not work anymore, the Counter Property is never updated in the Datebase.
Does someone know why?

Kind regards,
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - That method should be on the Page class (model), not the controller. You can then call $this->data()->countUp(); from the Page_Controller class.

2 - You need the line $this->write(); before $this->writeToStage('Stage');

Comment: there is still a strange thing... Counter is updated in the table Page_Live, but not in Page. the counter thing I solved now differently... I save the count in an separate DataObject for each page, cause updating and publishing a page always creates a new version in Page_versions

Comment: it is still strange: Counter is updated in the table Page_Live, but not in Page (which is Stage i think). If I edit the page in the CMS and then the Counter value of the table Page is displayed (0). Publishing overwrites then the Page_Live Counter with 0. I saw that the function $this->writeToStage('Stage'); is updating the Page table. But If there is added $this->write(); before then just Page_Live is updated. the same is for all 3 functions together (write, writeToStage, publish). Bug of feature?

Comment: Your `writeToStage() / publish()` code is correct.  But the method should really be on the `Page` class, not the `Page_Controller`

Comment: thanks, finally i solved it a bit differently. i created an "counter" - dataobject related to each page. so when  updating the count, there is no new version of the page created (because for page the versioning is activated of course).